# Apache Lucene LatLonPoint Query on Geode

Tags: java, lucene, geolocation, geospatial, geode

I am trying to index some geospatial data on a `Lucene` index which created on a Geode region, and run queries on these datas with `Lucene's LatLonPoint` class query methods (like `newDistanceQuery` or `newPolygonQuery` methods). Running the application once returns correct results but when I run the code for second time I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: 
no segments* file found in RegionDirectory@4218500f lockFactory=
org.apache.lucene.store.SingleInstanceLockFactory@4bff64c2: files: []
```

Here is the classes:

Server.java

```
public class Server {
final static Logger _logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Server.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    startServer();
}

/** Start a Geode Cache Server with a locator */
public static void startServer() throws InterruptedException {
    ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new ServerLauncher.Builder()
            .setMemberName("server1")
            .setServerPort(40404)
            .set("start-locator", "127.0.0.1[10334]")
            .set("jmx-manager", "true")
            .set("jmx-manager-start", "true")
            .build();

    ServerLauncher.ServerState state = serverLauncher.start();
    _logger.info(state.toString());

    Cache cache = new CacheFactory().create();
    createLuceneIndex(cache);
    cache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.PARTITION).create("locationsRegion");
}

/** Create a Lucene Index with given cache */
public static void createLuceneIndex(Cache cache) throws InterruptedException {
    LuceneService luceneService = LuceneServiceProvider.get(cache);
    luceneService.createIndexFactory()
            .addField("NAME")
            .addField("LOCATION")
            .addField("COORDINATES")
            .create("locationsIndex", "locationsRegion");
}
}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {
private static ClientCache cache;
private static Region<Integer, Document> region;

public static void main(String[] args) throws LuceneQueryException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    init();
    indexFiles();
    search();
}

/** Initialize the client cache and region */
private static void init() {
    cache = new ClientCacheFactory()
            .addPoolLocator("localhost", 10334)
            .create();

    if (cache != null) {
        region = cache.<Integer, Document>createClientRegionFactory(
                ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY).create("locationsRegion");
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Client cache is null");
    }
}

/** Add documents to the Lucene index */
private static void indexFiles() {
    // Dummy data
    List<Document> locations = Arrays.asList(
            DocumentBuilder.newSampleDocument("Exastax", 40.984929, 29.133506),
            DocumentBuilder.newSampleDocument("Galata Tower", 41.025826, 28.974378),
            DocumentBuilder.newSampleDocument("St. Peter and St. Paul Church", 41.024757, 28.972950));

    // Standart IndexWriter initialization.
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    // Create a directory from geode region
    Directory directory = RawLucene.returnRegionDirectory(cache, region, "locationsIndex");
    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexWriter indexWriter;
    try {
        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);
        indexWriter.addDocuments(locations);
        indexWriter.commit();
        indexWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/** Search in the Lucene index */
private static void search() {
    try {
        DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(RawLucene.returnRegionDirectory(cache, region, "locationsIndex"));
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        Query query = LatLonPoint.newDistanceQuery("COORDINATES", 41.024873, 28.974346, 500);
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 10).scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreDocs.length; i++) {
            Document doc = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDocs[i].doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get("NAME") + " --- " + doc.get("LOCATION"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

RawLucene.java

```
public class RawLucene {
public static Directory returnRegionDirectory(ClientCache cache, Region region, String indexName) {
    return new RegionDirectory(region,new FileSystemStats(cache.getDistributedSystem(), indexName));
}
}
```

DocumentBuilder.java

```
public class DocumentBuilder {
public static Document newSampleDocument(String name, Double lat, Double lon) {
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new StoredField("NAME", name));
    document.add(new StoredField("LOCATION", lat + " " + lon));
    document.add(new LatLonPoint("COORDINATES", lat, lon));
    return document;
}
}
```

This is how I start the app:

1. Run the Server class
2. Run the Client class with all three methods (Initial run. Works fine and returns correct results)
3. Run the Client class without calling the `indexFiles` method. (Second run. This is where I get the exception)

Why the code is running fine for the first time and throws exception on second run?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a mix of geode's public API along with the internal class RegionDirectory. The public API only supports adding documents by adding objects directly to a region, and querying using the LuceneService.createQueryFactory().

The geode-lucene module does use RegionDirectory internally, but it uses it a bit differently than you have used it - instead of wrapping an entire region from the client side, it wraps individual buckets on the server side.

I think what is going on here is that RegionDirectory and the underlying FileSystem class are using some geode APIs that behave differently when you call them on the client. In particular, I think when the FileSystem class is looking for files, it is using Region.keySet, which with your caching client is going to return the list of files cached on the client side. I think that explains why you are getting the error about no files.

It's too bad that RegionDirectory is not a public API and doesn't really support the way you are trying to use it, because this looks like a good use case.